# NSPredicate for a where in query

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

### The setup

There is a core-data object `foo`  that has a many-to-many relation to another core-data object 'bar'. This `bar` has a property `barid` of type `int32`.

I have a NSArray of ints represented by NSNumbers (let's name it `intlist`).
I have a single `foo` object.

### The problem

I need to know how many `bar` object related to this `foo` instance have a `barid` that is included in the `intlist`.

I think I can use a predicate for this. But what format should my predicate have? in SQL it would be `SELECT count(*) FROM fooBarLinkTable WHERE fooid = x AND barid IN intlist`, but I don't know how to turn that statement into a predicate.

Comment: print your "array with dict" ....... then is easy to write predicate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that you have an inverse relationship bar<->foo and that `intlist` is type of NSArray or NSSet of NSNumber objects. If so then do following:

```
NSFetchRequest* request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"bar"];
[request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"barid IN %@ && ANY relationshipToFoos == %@", intlist, foo]];
NSError* error = nil;
NSUInteger count = [[self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext] countForFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

Comment: It should only be noted (because it is not clear from the question) that `intlist` must be an NSArray (or NSSet) of NSNumber objects. A C array of ints will not work in the predicate.

Comment: Yep, of course. I assume this. Thanks for note. Updated answer.

Comment: I have upvoted already and will accept wednesday when I get back to the office to test it out. The `intlist` is an NSArray. I'll edit that into the question.